Godot collision detection
area2D and Sprites with collisionShape2D
Im trying to get the following working- it's a player that moves by W via transform and moves to mouse cursor. What I cant get is the colision with a crate.
I made the area2d and attached to it a player sprite2d and a colisionshape2d with a recatangle
When i pass through the crate it does nothing
can anyone assist ive literally tried everything so far//
   extends Area2D


# Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
func _ready():
    pass # Replace with function body.


# Called every frame. 'delta' is the elapsed time since the previous frame.
func _process(delta):
    pass
    

func _on_area_entered(area):
    if area.name == "Player":
        print("PLAYER ENTERED THE CRATE");

Game 2D view click here

How are your collision layers/masks set up?

theyre set up as childs of the area2D

No, I mean this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c59PHMLrCj8

if you click on -->Game 2D view click here -- above it shows how the rectangles are for the collision2D i attached to the area2d which then has a sprite2d under it too

AH right thanks for replying with that..  i haven't touched layer / masks is that really nessesary though i havent watch all of that vid you posted yet just thought id reply

thanks for your video. Just watched it all there..  They are both on the same layer and not masked so it should work imo

Your Area2D must have its mask set to the layer on which the player lives in order to “notice” it! It should probably work if you activate the mask. Any reason you’re using an Area2D for your player, btw? Usually you’d use a CharacterBody2D. If you change to a CharacterBody2D, you’ll have to use the body_endered signal instead of area_entered.

Here’s a simple project with working collision (it writes to the console as you enter the area): https://wetransfer.com/downloads/47b4f5fee2c190e61006c2763f27f5f420240429212117/9cf8bd

Are you editing the transform position manually? If you're manually updating a Sprite2D's position, it's not doing collision checks. You just set the position to whatever you want.
You could tap into the Area2D's area_entered signal to perform a manual check to see if your movement would cause an intersection, and then undo the movement if it would, but that's not what I would recommend.
I can't know your specific use case, but if I were in your situation I would want to replace the player with a CharacterBody2D node. You can add your sprite and collider to this node, and you can use the CharacterBody's move_and_slide function to move your character, instead of editing the transform yourself. This is, for most use cases, the intended solution for a player-controlled 2D object in Godot.
Hope this helped!

Thanks for the help with this people. I will try the characterbody2d node! Cheers
